# Implementing a genetic algorithm to solve knapsack

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to develop a genetic algorithm to solve knapsack problem(0-1). I am new to algorithm and programming as well. Here is my code and it works but I would like to know your suggestions of how to improve it.

**Knapsack.h**

```
#ifndef KNAPSACK_H
#define KNAPSACK_H
#include <vector>
#include <random>

class knapsack
{

public:
    struct population
    {
        int fitness;
        int weight;
        int pop[5];
    };

public:

    knapsack();

    void initPopulation(std::vector<population> &pop, std::vector<knapsack::population> &initBuffer);
    void calFitness(std::vector<population> &pop, int userInput[][5]);

    void sortByFitness(std::vector<population> &sort);

    void mate(std::vector<population> &mate1, std::vector<population> &mate2);
    void copyNewGeneration(std::vector<population> &copyFrom, std::vector<population> &copyTo);
    void mutate(std::vector<population> &mutate, std::vector<population> &buffer);

    void swap(std::vector<knapsack::population> &pop, std::vector<knapsack::population> &buffer);

    int randGenerate(int start, int end);

    void print(std::vector<knapsack::population> &pop);

    void solve(int userInput[][5]);

private:
    int popSize;
    int maxB;
    int maxW;
    int bagWeight;

public:
    std::default_random_engine dRandom;
};



#endif
```

**implementation.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Knapsack.h"

typedef std::vector<knapsack::population> chromosomes;

knapsack::knapsack():dRandom(), popSize(10), maxB(0), maxW(0), bagWeight(20){}

void knapsack::initPopulation( chromosomes &initPop,  chromosomes &initBuffer)
{
    knapsack::population p;

    int gene = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < popSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            gene = randGenerate(0, 2);
            p.pop[j] = gene;
        }

        initPop.push_back(p);
    }

    initBuffer.resize(popSize);
}

int knapsack::randGenerate(int start, int end)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> genenNum(start, end - 1);

    return genenNum(dRandom);
}
void knapsack::calFitness( chromosomes &pop, int userInput[][5])
{
    int fit    = 0;
    int weight = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < popSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if(pop[i].pop[j] == 1)
            {
                weight         += userInput[0][j];
                fit            += userInput[1][j];
                pop[i].weight  = weight;
                pop[i].fitness = fit;

                if(weight > bagWeight)  pop[i].fitness = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                weight         += 0;
                fit            += 0;
                pop[i].weight  = weight;
                pop[i].fitness = fit;
            }

        }
        weight = 0;
        fit    = 0;
    }

}

void knapsack::copyNewGeneration( chromosomes &copyFrom,  chromosomes &copyTo)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < popSize;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            copyTo[i].pop[j] = copyFrom[i].pop[j];
        }

        copyTo[i].fitness = copyFrom[i].fitness;
    }
}

void knapsack::mutate( chromosomes &mutate,  chromosomes &buffer)
{

    int pIndex1 = randGenerate(0, popSize);
    int  pIndex2= randGenerate(0, popSize);

    int index1 = randGenerate(0, 5);
    int index2 = randGenerate(0, 5);


    buffer[pIndex1].pop[index1] = mutate[pIndex2].pop[index2];



}

void knapsack::mate( chromosomes &mate1,  chromosomes &mate2)
{
   copyNewGeneration(mate1,mate2);

   for(int i= 0; i < 5; i++ )
   {
       int index1 = randGenerate(0, 5);
       int index2 = randGenerate(0, 5);


       if(mate2[i].weight < bagWeight || mate2[i].weight > bagWeight)
         {
             mate2[index1].pop[i] = mate1[index2].pop[i];
         } 

   }

   mutate(mate1,mate2);
}

void knapsack::sortByFitness( chromosomes &sort)
{

    std::sort(sort.begin(),sort.end(),
        []( const population & x, const population & y) -> bool { return( x.fitness > y.fitness);} );
}

void knapsack::swap( chromosomes &pop,  chromosomes &buffer)
{
     chromosomes *temp = &pop;
     pop = buffer;
     buffer = *temp;
}

void knapsack::print( chromosomes &pop)
{

    if(pop[0].fitness > maxB)
       {
           maxB = pop[0].fitness;
       }

    std::cout<< " Max Benefit : "<<maxB<<std::endl;
}

void knapsack::solve(int userInput[][5])
{

     chromosomes initPop, initBuffer, *pop, *buffer;


    initPopulation(initPop, initBuffer);

    pop    = &initPop;
    buffer = &initBuffer;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        calFitness(*pop, userInput);
        sortByFitness(*pop);
        print(*pop);            
        mate(*pop,*buffer);
        swap(*pop,*buffer);

    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));

    int u[2][5] = {{2 , 7 , 1 , 4 , 1},{5 , 3 , 2 , 9 , 6}};

    knapsack ks;

    ks.solve(u);


    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the purpose of this code to organize an inventory using GA? [I once tried that](https://code.google.com/p/inventoryd/) and it failed miserably :P But that is my fault, I must have done something wrong. Anyway, I gave up once I found that the brute force approach was so much faster. hehehe

Comment: @glampert, I think you are right, brute force or dynamic programming would be much better approach for this problem, but I am trying to learn something different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Naming of C++ types:**

User defined C++ types are usually named using `CamelCase`, with the first letter
upper case. Lowe-case names are commonly used by the standard library.
I suggest you rename your types `knapsack` and `population` to `Knapsack` and `Population` instead.

**Make internal stuff private:**

I don't see a reason for the random generator `dRandom` to be public.
Actually, the only method being called by `main()` is `knapsack::solve()`.
If no other method is meant to be called outside the class, put those in the
private section (except for the constructor and destructor, of course).

**Some mix-up with typedef:**

In `implementation.cpp` you have a `chromosomes` typedef that you consistently 
use. However, in `Knapsack.h` you are using `std::vector<population>` instead.
Why this mix-up? Place the typedef in the class header, right below `struct population` and use it everywhere.

**Re-implementing `swap()`:**

Your class implements its own `swap()` method. Which is redundant
with [`std::swap()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/), the standard swap function. Use the standard one
instead. Chances are that it is much more optimized and efficient than yours.

But wait, there is more! Your `swap` function is actually incorrect.

```
void knapsack::swap( chromosomes &pop,  chromosomes &buffer)
{
     chromosomes *temp = &pop; // 1. temp points to pop
     pop = buffer;             // 2. pop is now = buffer
     buffer = *temp;           // 3. buffer is now = whatever temp points at, which is = pop
}
```

This function is basically a one-way copy. First (1), you save the *address*, not the value, of `pop` in the `temp` pointer. So `*temp` is the same as `pop`.

Second (2) you overwrite `pop` with the contents of `buffer`. Now `pop` is equal to buffer.

Third (3) you overwrite `buffer` with the contents of whatever `temp` points to. But `temp` points to `pop` and `pop` is already equal to `buffer`, so you are basically 
writing buffer over `pop` and then writing it back to `buffer`. So `buffer` is never actually changed.

**Const correctness:**

`knapsack::print()` is only reading from its input parameter. When a function/method
only reads from a param, that param should be made const. This is even more important
when the parameter is passed by reference, as it is the case here. This is called [const correctness](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html).

```
void knapsack::print(const chromosomes &pop) { ... }
```

**`srand()` is unnecessary in this context:**

```
srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
```

Is useless here. `std::default_random_engine` cannot be seeded that way.
If you want to seed it by the current time, see an example of how to do it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/linear_congruential_engine/linear_congruential_engine/).

**5s?**

You've used the constant `5` in several places. Is this just a coincidence
or does 5 actually mean something to your program?

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
...
int index1 = randGenerate(0, 5);
int index2 = randGenerate(0, 5);
...
void knapsack::solve(int userInput[][5])
```

Give that constant a meaningful name (a class scoped `static const int`)
and replace those raw 5s with it.

**Blank lines and some indentation problems:**

Your code has a few lines with bad indenting, like these:

```
if(pop[0].fitness > maxB)
   {
       maxB = pop[0].fitness;
   }
```

And a few excessive blank lines in some places, like here:

```
void knapsack::solve(int userInput[][5])
{

     chromosomes initPop, initBuffer, *pop, *buffer;


    initPopulation(initPop, initBuffer);
```

Fix this to make your code neater and easier to read.

Comment: I am using something like this **calFitness( chromosomes &pop, int userInput[][5])** in my code but I would like the array's size to not be fixed and based on the user choice, how I can do that can you please help me ?

Comment: @Code_LOVER, you mean the `userInput[][]` 2d array? This question is probably a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17569578/1198654